# Issue using Black formatter in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, application-settings, ide-customization, black-code-formatter

I am trying to setup the formatter "**black**" to work with PyCharm. I have tried setting it up with both the standard External Tools preferences and using the Files Watcher Plugin. Neither has worked for me.

**I am getting these errors:**

[image: PyCharm Errors in the run console]

I have it installed in `/Users/Scott/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/black.py` and want it to run globally for all Python project files when I save.

**This is how my preferences look:**

[image: PyCharm External Tools configuration for the black formatter]

I am new to Python and PyCharm and Stack Overflow for that matter, and am stilling setting this up. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Consider using plugins, e.g. https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10563-black-pycharm or https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14321-blackconnect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `.py` file as a command. You need to add `python` to tell which program can execute this code.

Alternatively, you can use `black` executable if it is installed in your python environment.

[image]

Comment: this works, but how can i trigger this to run on save?

Comment: I believe this is not implemented in PyCharm, but you can try a trick like this: https://marcesher.com/2014/03/30/intellij-idea-run-goimports-on-file-save/

Answer (score 1):

You have to install  Black using pip install black[d] not from pycharm console in a project but at your python directory  then install from Pycharm>file>settings..>plugins, (BlackConnect plugin), and it will work for sure. about trigger this on save.

Pycharm Settings
[image: Pycharm Settings]

or press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>